# Dart Extension Method defined on subtype is not recognised

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following extension method defined on a List of Comparable elements:

```
extension ComparableList<T extends Comparable<T>> on List<T> {
  int doSomething() {
    // This is just an example
    return this.first.compareTo(this.last);
  }
}
```

Then I'm trying to use it on a `List<num>`. The definition of `num` is `abstract class num implements Comparable<num>` so this should work I think.

```
class Example<T extends num> {
  final List<T> list;

  Example(this.list) {
    list.doSomething(); // This throws "error: The method 'doSomething' isn't defined for the class 'List'."
  }
}
```

If I change the definition of the extension method to `extension ComparableList<T extends num> on List<T>` everything works fine however, I want this to be defined for all comparable classes.

Comment: Have you imported the extension?

Comment: Yes, it's imported. Changing `Comparable<T>` to `num` in the extension definition makes it compile fine (and I'm able to use the method defined inside).

Comment: Does this help? `extension ComparableList<T extends Comparable<T>> on List<Comparable<T>> {`

Comment: Yes! That actually did the trick! Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm going to post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`extension ComparableList<T extends Comparable<T>> on List<T>`

to

`extension ComparableList<T extends Comparable<T>> on List<Comparable<T>>`

so that Dart knows the type.